# SQLite Select statement when have multiples rows

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, android-sqlite

I want select * from a table comparing 3 rows and the select return an id, i create this method:

```
//UserDAO class

private SQLiteDatabase mDatabase;
private DatabaseHelper mDbHelper;

// irelative code

public Long selectUserLogin(String nickname, String chapter, String password) {
    long id;
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " +
            DatabaseHelper.TABLE_USERS + " WHERE " +
            DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_USERS_NICKNAME + " = " + nickname + " AND " +
            DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_USERS_CHAPTER + " = " + chapter + " AND " +
            DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_USERS_PASSWORD + " = " + password;

    Log.e(TAG, selectQuery);
    try {
        Cursor cursor = mDatabase.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.moveToFirst();

        id = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_USERS_ID));

        return id;
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Already created on my database nickname = q, chapter = Q and password = qqqqqq

These is where i called the method to test his functionality

```
userDAO.selectUserLogin("q", "Q", "qqqqqq");
```

I checked with another method that list all my users and i get all the users I've one time created.

Here is the results:

```
10-09 01:00:18.298 10978-10978/com.org.feedme.cisvmeeting.activities     D/LeaderFragment: User: [
D/LeaderFragment: [1] 1, h, h, G 
D/LeaderFragment: [2] 2, fkfkdk, fjfkdk, SAO 
D/LeaderFragment: [3] 3, Filipe fila, Fil36
D/LeaderFragment: [4] 4, q, Q, qqqqqq
D/LeaderFragment: [5] 5, glgl, vmlc, GOLGO]
```

When i tried to see my data folder on Android Device Monitor the folder was empty, so i'm little bit confused if i could not access the database or if i'm not inserting correctly.

Part of my logcat when i tried call the method *selectUserLogin*:

> 10-09 00:46:01.198 7745-7745/com.org.feedme.cisvmeeting.activities
>   E/UserDAO: SELECT  * FROM users WHERE nickname = q AND chapter = Q AND
>   password = qqqqqq
>
> 10-09 00:46:01.208 7745-7745/com.org.feedme.cisvmeeting.activities
>   E/SQLiteLog: (1) no such column: q
>
> 10-09 00:46:01.208 7745-7745/com.org.feedme.cisvmeeting.activities
>   W/System.err: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column:
>   q (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT  * FROM users WHERE nickname = q
>   AND chapter = Q AND password = qqqqqq

EDIT: I only run my app on my android device!

EDIT_2: I tested another similar method and these second one is working fine!

```
public String selectUser(long id) {
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + DatabaseHelper.TABLE_USERS +
            " WHERE " + DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_USERS_ID + "=" + id ;
    String result = null;
    Log.e(TAG, selectQuery);
    Cursor cursor = mDatabase.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        result = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_USERS_NAME));
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: check if your database is created and if you have inserted data using emulator

Comment: Check whether the table you created has the correct field names.

Comment: i running on my device!

Comment: @FilipeFilardi, can you try adding single quotes around the equals arguments to see if that has any effect like this: `" = '" + nickname + "' AND " `

Comment: @jyanks tried, but still having problem! thanx for the suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to surround the string arguments in quotes, since you are not using selectionArgs (the second parameter in `rawQuery`).

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " +
        DatabaseHelper.TABLE_USERS + " WHERE " +
        DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_USERS_NICKNAME + " = '" + nickname + "' AND " +
        DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_USERS_CHAPTER + " = '" + chapter + "' AND " +
        DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_USERS_PASSWORD + " = '" + password + "' ";

Log.e(TAG, selectQuery);
try {
    Cursor cursor = mDatabase.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
```

Or you can do this, which will take care of the strings for you.

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " +
        DatabaseHelper.TABLE_USERS + " WHERE " +
        DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_USERS_NICKNAME + "=? AND " +
        DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_USERS_CHAPTER + "=? AND " +
        DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_USERS_PASSWORD + "=? ";

String[] selectionArgs = new String[] { nickname, chapter, password };

Log.e(TAG, selectQuery);
try {
    Cursor cursor = mDatabase.rawQuery(selectQuery, selectionArgs);
```

Comment: tried the two methods and get these errors -->CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
and java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: This code is correct, assuming that your database is setup properly. You can do `String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + DatabaseHelper.TABLE_USERS"` and then call `mDatabase.rawQuery(selectQuery, null).getCount();` to see if there are actually rows in your database.

Comment: also, I'd change the if block from `if (cursor != null) { cursor.moveToFirst(); }` to: `if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) { return id from cursor }` so that you can make sure there are actual rows to return data for.

Comment: thanks for all the tips, the `"SELECT * FROM " + DatabaseHelper.TABLE_USERS"` returned 5, so i guess the problem is not the database!

Comment: Thanks man, one of the problems was the quotes and other was the `.getText().toString()` of one parameter!!! Solved now thanks to u!

Answer (score 0):

first of all you remove you application on your device and then reinstall the application now insert the data you needed and now whatever you entered data is remember and apply those data on your query parameter for select.

Comment: Tried these, but nothing happened